# How to build xsl:attribute-sets for multiple XML-Items?

Tags: php, xml, xslt

i want to transform a xml with the XSLTProcessor. Everthing is working fine but i got problems with the attribute-sets.

My XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<exportDelivery>
<job>/* many other tags and data */</job>
<job>/* many other tags and data */</job>
<job>/* many other tags and data */</job>
</exportDelivery>
```

If you want to use attributes in your new xml you have to use attribue-sets in the xsl-file. But attribute-sets have to be defined in the "head" of the xsl. that means outside of the foreach-loop for the "job"-tags. 
After the Transformation every job gets the same attributes of the first job. What did i wrong? Here is a attribue-set i use:

```
  <xsl:attribute-set name="premium">
    <xsl:attribute name="from">
      <xsl:value-of select="/exportDelivery/jobAdvertisements/startDate"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="to">
      <xsl:value-of select="/exportDelivery/jobAdvertisements/endDate"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

attribute-sets are used as a shorthand for providing multiple attributes at once, so instead of writing:

```
<xsl:attribute name="border">5</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="cellpadding">15</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:attribute name="cellspacing">10</xsl:attribute>
```

every time we want to specify all three at once, one may specify an attribute-set to do it in one line

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="set_table">...</xsl:attribute-set>

<table xsl:use-attribute-sets="set_table">
```

These "attribute-sets" can only be defined once.
in your case, don't you want to do something like this?

```
<job>
  <premium from="blaDate" to="fooDate"/>
</job>
```

if so, i don't see, what's stopping you from inserting these elements during the transformation:

```
<xsl:template match="job">
  <job>
    <xsl:attribute name="from">
      <xsl:value-of select="/exportDelivery/jobAdvertisements/startDate"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </job>
</xsl:template>
```

maybe you need to explain a little further, what you are trying to achieve exactly

Answer (score 2):

**In addition to the correct answer of @mindlandmedia, in many cases it is possible to specify both an element and its attributes, using what is known as the "[AVT](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#attribute-value-templates)" notation**:

```
<job from="{/exportDelivery/jobAdvertisements/startDate}"/>
```